# Adobe Flash ActionScript 2 if statement _currentframe

Tags: if-statement, adobe, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

For a class assignment, I'm creating a game. I want to make it so when you score enough points, you'll proceed to the next frame. However, the code I put int he Actions layer won't work. Whenever I score enough points, it just stays on the same frame. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I used:

`if(score_mc._currentframe == 6){
    _root.gotoAndStop("next");
}`

Adobe Flash CS6
ActionScript 2.0

Comment: is that condition evaluated continuously (for example in an enterFrame function or setInterval ) ?...otherwise it might be evaluated only once when that frame is reached

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use `score_mc.nextFrame();` or something like that for increment you score. You could add this check you made right after this incrementation. So it will be

```
score_mc.nextFrame();
if(score_mc._currentframe == 6){
     _root.gotoAndStop("next");
}
```